# Fragments inside bottom navigation view items

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

How to inside some fragments in bottom navigation view spesific tabs. Can i use NavHost navigation component? thanks, sorry bad english.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe there is another better way.

Comment: I use bottom navigation view i want to example : inside home fragment when click some button or textview or etc, open another fragment inside home tab

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood correctly you want to display a fragment from another fragment. 
One of the options would be to use [FragmentTransation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction).

In case you use Kotlin:

```
// Replace YourNextFragment with fragment class name you want to show
val fragment: YourNextFragment = YourNextFragment()
val transaction = parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
// R.id.container should be replaced with resource ID of FrameLayout or fragment
// tag that you use to display fragments
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
transaction.addToBackStack(fragment::class.java.simpleName)
transaction.commit()
```

In case you use Java:

```
// Replace YourNextFragment with fragment class name you want to show
YourNextFragment fragment = YourNextFragment();
FragmentTransation transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
// R.id.container should be replaced with resource ID of FrameLayout or fragment
// tag that you use to display fragments
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.class.getSimpleName());
transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.class.getSimpleName());
transaction.commit();
```